# Can't find algorithm for specific rules

Tags: algorithm, rust

I'm trying to implement in rust an algorithm that given a number generate
an array containing every combinations possible obeying to those rules:

- A number in the combination is always equal or less than the previous one
- No number greater than 4 are accepted
- A combinations ends when the sum of the number containing it is equal the given number

For the example, given the number 3, we will get the following array:

```
[    
    [3],
    [2, 1],
    [1, 1, 1],
]
```

And given the number 6:

```
[    
    [4, 2],
    [4, 1, 1],
    [3, 3],
    [3, 2, 1],
    [3, 1, 1, 1],
    [2, 2, 2],
    [2, 2, 1, 1],
    [2, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
]
```

I'm trying to develop this in rust, but since i'm quite new to the language and do not have an algorithm to rely upon i need some help. Whether pseudo code or code without GC will be fine.

Comment: That's a problem not a question. Try to implement something and then come back and [edit] with specific questions you came across while doing so.

Comment: I ask the question because i'm stuck...

Comment: Then add where you are stuck, show what you've tried...

Comment: @cafce25 any idea where to post if not in stackoverflow

I know it's a problem not a code question and a response in pseudo algo would be just fine.

If stack overflow is for code only (did not know that prior) would you know any forum where algorithmic questions are accepted ?

Comment: @cafce25 it's way too cahotic

I'll try to implement it with garbage collection (in js most likely) then i'll know if i'm blocked because of the algo or rust

Comment: It's totally fine to post on SO but don't just add the problem statement. Add the code you've tried, what you expected, what you got instead, why it doesn't work, etc. [ask] and it's links has a bunch of material on how to write a good question. Just copy pasting a solution provided here might get you a quick solution to the specific problem at hand but it probably won't help you get any better. It's also very unlikely to help anyone else which SO is all about.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think the below code does what you want.

```py
res = []


def generate_combinations(num, current_combination):
    # base case
    if num < 0:
        return
    if num == 0:
        res.append(current_combination.copy())
        return
    # recursion
    if current_combination:
        end = current_combination[-1]
    else:
        end = 4
    for i in range(end, 0, -1):
        current_combination.append(i)
        generate_combinations(num - i, current_combination)
        current_combination.pop()
```